# How to cancel download when the <img/> tag disppears?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a simple tag `<img url="myurl.com/123"/>`. Now, I use react to generate them with random URLs every second, and it always replaces the last one. I noticed that with a slow connection, the images will start loading, but not stop even when I replace the current tag. Instead, they will download the picture and do nothing with it. What I would want to happen, is that when the tag with this image disappears, the image stops loading and instead the next one starts. Is there a good way to do that? I know there is the `load="lazy"` attribute, but this only prevents an image that isn't on the screen from loading, and won't actually cancel it.

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: Create images in memory, then append to HTML. https://css-tricks.com/pre-caching-image-with-react-suspense/

Comment: I don't believe you can control the process of retrieving an image resource once it has been started. But this feels like you're trying to work around the real problem: If an image is taking longer to load than it will be on screen, then you need to either drastically reduce the image sizes, or display the images for longer. Cancelling previous images won't fix the issue, at best it would just stop it from getting worse over time.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, instead of an `<img>` we can do the following:

`<div style={{ backgroundImage: "url(www.image.com)"}}/>`, and then requests will be canceled whenever the div is unmounted.